# Adding custom SOAP headers to client generated by weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.ClientGenTask?

Tags: web-services, weblogic, header

I generated a client using the weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.ClientGenTask from weblogic.  Now I want to insert custom soap headers before sending out the request.  How do I go about doing that?  All of the examples on the web for inserting headers are specific to the library used in the generation (Axis, etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webserv/client.html

Google "Client Handler Chain".  Extend GenericHandler and setup a handler xml before generating your client.

Cheers!